# How to draw a circle by polyline in CADlib?

Tags: c#, cad, dwg

In the demand, I should draw a circle by polyline ,which should draw by a software developed by C# and the library CADlib.

This is the document about polyline:

http://www.woutware.com/doc/cadlib4.0/html/3a2347ab-838e-26ca-5aed-889ec5f96526.htm

I could not find the way to draw a circle by polyline,could someone tell me the use of CADlib about it ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can check this article for using CadLib:        
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3398/CadLib-for-creating-DXF-Drawing-Interchange-Format

Comment: http://www.woutware.com/doc/cadlib4.0/html/89982686-291c-f360-599f-c3bb3be7bbaa.htm  ;  Public method DxfLwPolyline.Vertex(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double) ; This is about circle by polyline,thanks anyway.